# How do I compile an ORACLE trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have an invalid ORACLE trigger.

How can I compile it with SQL*PLUS?

How can I see the status with SQL*PLUS?

Comment: what exactly does invalid mean in your understanding?

Comment: If everything else fails, read the instructions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/alter_trigger.htm#LNPLS99996

Comment: It is TOAD using that term.  In this case its a sequence used by the trigger missing, if you install the sequence, the trigger is still invalid it has to be recompiled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can recompile using [`ALTER TRIGGER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_triggers.htm#BABGJJGC):

```
ALTER TRIGGER myTrigger COMPILE
```

If SQLPlus reports `Trigger compiled with errors` (or something similar), just type `SHOW ERRORS` for more information.

Comment: About the second point I was looking for a seperate SQL*PLUS statement I can send over.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but here's a guess... The `Status` column in the `User_Triggers` view appears to be `ENABLED` or `DISABLED` so that's not the one. In the `User_Objects` view the `Status` for type `TRIGGER` is `VALID` or `INVALID` so that's probably the one. Try this: `SELECT Status FROM User_Objects WHERE Object_Name = 'your-trigger-name' AND Object_Type = 'TRIGGER'`.